# Haskell: Understanding generalised algebraic data types

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have the following code, which outlines a language of boolean and arithmetic expressions:

```
data Exp a where
     Plus :: Exp Int -> Exp Int -> Exp Int
     Const :: (Show a) => a -> Exp a 
     Not :: Exp Bool -> Exp Bool
     And :: Exp Bool -> Exp Bool -> Exp Bool
     Greater :: Exp Int -> Exp Int -> Exp Bool
```

The evaluation function for the above language has the following type:

```
eval :: Exp a -> a
```

I am trying to understand what are the possible types the `eval` function can return. The above code uses GADTs which enable the type Exp a to be defined in terms of the type signatures of its constructors.
The return type of the constructors is not always Exp a. I believe that the types `eval` can return include Int, Bool, or a value of any type implementing Show. However, is it possible for `eval` to return any other type besides the three I mentioned previously (since the return type of the function is `a`)? Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: There are no three types, since `Show` covers an infinite set of types. The wording  "*or a value of any type implementing Show*" is also not strictly correct, it should be *or any type implementing Show*

Comment: So would it be correct to say that the evaluation function can return any type?

Comment: @ceno980 it can return any type that implements `Show`, more accurately.

Comment: In order to evaluate `eval`, you need a value of type `Exp a`. Such value can be created by one of the five constructors, and `Const` allows any type implementing `Show` to be boxed there.

Comment: Given the type `Exp a -> a`, it is possible *if the definition of `Exp` changes*. Do so would increase the number of values belonging to the type `Exp a -> a`. You are basically asking for the union of `image(f)` for all possible functions `f :: Exp a -> a`.

Answer (score 3):

`Exp a -> a` is a type that could have *many* possible functions. For example, a valid function that probably *isn't* the one you are thinking of as "the" `eval` function is

```
foo :: Exp a -> a
foo (Plus _ _) = 3
foo (Const x) = x
foo (Not _) = True
foo (And _ _) = True
foo (Greater _ _) = True
```

The *image* of a function is the set of values it can return. This example demonstrates that the function `foo` and the `eval` you are expecting have different images, despite having the same return type `forall a. a`.

You are asking, in essence, what the *union* of all possible images of functions of type `Exp a -> a` is. This depends greatly on the actual definition of `Exp`. As currently defined, that would be the union of `Int`, `Bool`, and `Show a => a`.

`Exp` the type constructor, though, is capable of defining *uninhabited* types. The type `Exp (Int -> Int)` exists, even though you haven't defined a constructor which can create values of that type. Since you can't provide a value of type `Exp (Int -> Int)` for any potential `eval` function, it can't affect the image of any such function, either.

Changing the definition of `Exp` to include such a constructor would increase the set of values that could be passed to a function of type `Exp a -> a`, thus increase the set of values that could occur in the image of such a function.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, given your definition of `Exp` above, the answer is "yes":  any function with type signature `eval :: Exp a -> a` can only return a (defined) value of type `Int`, `Bool`, or some other type with a `Show` instance.  Because any type (of kind `*`) can be given a `Show` instance, that technically means that `eval` can return any type, but within a particular program that has a fixed set of `Show` instances, `eval` will be limited to returning values from this set of types.

You can see that this must be true as follows.  Suppose that `eval e` returned a value of some fixed type `t` for some expression `e`.  By the type signature of `eval`, that would imply that `e` must have type `Exp t`.  However, data type declarations are "closed" meaning that the set of constructors given in the `data Exp a` declaration is exhaustive, and they represent the only methods of constructing a (defined) value of type `Exp a`.  It's clear from the set of constructors that the only possible values of type `Exp a` are those that appear in the rightmost positions of the constructors' signatures:  `Exp Int`, `Exp Bool`, and `Exp a` with the constraint `Show a`.  Therefore, these are the only types possible for `e` implying that `t` must be `Int`, `Bool`, or some other `a` satisfying the constraint `Show a`.

As always in reasoning about Haskell types, we have to be a little bit careful in considering undefined/bottom values.  If you consider "returning an undefined value" to be meaningful, then, indeed, `eval` can "return" an undefined value of any type, even one without a `Show` instance.  For example, the following will typecheck:

```
stupid :: Exp (Int -> Int)
stupid = eval undefined
```

However, if your reason for asking the question is to determine whether you'd ever be in a position where the expression `eval e` might unexpectedly have a type other than `Int`, `Bool`, or some `Show a => a` that you would somehow have to handle, then no.  The form of the GADT places limits on the possible types `a` in the signature `eval :: Exp a -> a`.